# Can anyone explain how to properly write the WHERE clause with a True/False element?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I took two tries at this test and got this question wrong both times. I don't understand how to write the WHERE clause. I thought it didn't need the "" marks as the columns I believe had yes/no values. Is it just the OR that needs to be selected, and does it work with our without the quotations? - I'm just a confused newbie, thanks for any clarification.

You finish cleaning your datasets, so you decide to review Tayen’s email one more time to make sure you completed the task fully. It’s a good thing you checked because you forgot to identify people who have served on the board of directors or board of trustees. She wants to write them a thank-you note, so you need to locate them in the database.

To retrieve only those records that include people who have served on the board of trustees or on the board of directors, what is the correct query?

0 / 1 point

```
SELECT *
FROM Donation_Form_List
WHERE Board_Member = TRUE AND Trustee = TRUE



SELECT *
FROM Donation_Form_List
WHERE Board_Member = "TRUE" AND Trustee = "TRUE"



SELECT *
FROM Donation_Form_List
WHERE Board_Member = TRUE, Trustee = TRUE



SELECT *
FROM Donation_Form_List
WHERE Board_Member = "TRUE" OR Trustee = "TRUE"
```

Incorrect

Review the section on SQL functions for a refresher.

Comment: What is your actual SQL _database_ (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.)?  We need to know this in order to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two columns with boolean values in database and managing status in those columns then following query should return you data for (board_member + trustee)

```
SELECT * FROM Donation_Form_List 
WHERE 
(Board_Member = True OR Trustee = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't actually have booleans as a data type. It's common to represent True and False values as 1 and 0.

If you actually wanted to store the word True you would need to store it as a VARCHAR which would require quotes to look up.

I think that's what the question is getting at.

Comment: Thanks! That helps me some. I still thought that the "" marks around the word True in a WHERE clause would make the Query look for the exact word True. I thought quotes always meant, as is, or literally. So quotes around true means that it's looking for the word True in the Board_Member or Trustee columns, which I would assume would be a Yes/No or a check box type value, so the "True" was confusing. I suppose if it means 1 or 0, 1 being yes and 0 being no, then it could make a little sense. Still a bit confused but I am new to data analytics, sql and bigquery so...trying my best.